# Grouping data with SQL Hana

Tags: sql, group-by, hana, gaps-and-islands

I have the following dataset structure.

[image]

Where column status means 1 - quit, 0 - employed. I was wondering how can I write an SQL query to group
by Employee ID in order to show the rime period from the time they joined(or re-joined) the company to the time they quit/end of period. Where if an employee quit a job and rejoined later they'd be represented in different unique fields. So the resulting dataframe should look like this:

[image]

I'm trying to learn SQL dialect for HANA. And not quite sure how can I group by both ID and the status in the way to handle those re-joining cases.

Thank you!

Comment: Ooops, my bad. Edited the initial post to show the correct interpretation of the data.
Basically group by the employee from them joining/re-joining the company to them quitting or the end of known info.

Comment: I would have interpreted the data differently. 1st Jan 2000, to 1st Mar 2000, Employee 1 is in status "Quit". The first "Joined" row for Employee 1 is from 26th March 2002 to 10th May 2002. Your result would suggest all 1-s for Status in the first 4 rows ordered by employee id and from-date. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your status column completely; just relying on time gaps between the rows.

Saw your edit in the meantime. With that, you can also check for `LAG(status) OVER() IS NULL OR LAG(status) OVER() = 0` for the calculation of the counter.

And please, please - add your data so that we can copy-paste them into a working space instead of tapping them in patiently by hand...

oh - and I assumed (as I have no SAP HANA handy) THAT <date> - <date> returns an Integer, in SAP HANA, too. Otherwise, work with DAYS_BETWEEN() ...

```
WITH 
-- your input as table "indata"
indata(emp_id,dt_from,dt_to,status) AS (
            SELECT 1,DATE '2000-01-01',DATE '2000-03-01',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2000-03-02',DATE '2000-06-25',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2000-06-26',DATE '2002-03-25',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2002-03-26',DATE '2002-05-10',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2005-02-15',DATE '2005-07-01',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2005-07-02',DATE '2005-09-03',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2005-09-04',DATE '2006-02-11',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2000-08-02',DATE '2000-11-20',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2000-11-21',DATE '2001-08-12',1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2001-08-13',DATE '2002-02-15',1
)
-- ignore existing "status"; just rely on gaps in the time line;
-- add a counter that is at 0 when first row or no gap to 
-- predecessor, else at 1
,
with_counter AS (
  SELECT
    emp_id
  , dt_from
  , dt_to
  , dt_from - LAG(dt_to) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY dt_from) as gapsize
  , CASE WHEN LAG(dt_to) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY dt_from) IS NULL 
           OR dt_from - LAG(dt_to) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY dt_from) = 1
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
    END AS counter
  FROM indata
)
-- create a session id as running sum previous counter
,
with_session AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , SUM(counter) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY dt_from) AS sess_id
  FROM with_counter
)
SELECT
  emp_id
, MIN(dt_from) AS dt_from
, MAX(dt_to)   AS dt_to
FROM with_session
GROUP BY 
  emp_id
, sess_id
ORDER BY
  emp_id
, 2
;
-- out  emp_id |  dt_from   |   dt_to    
-- out --------+------------+------------
-- out       1 | 2000-01-01 | 2002-05-10
-- out       1 | 2005-02-15 | 2006-02-11
-- out       2 | 2000-08-02 | 2002-02-15
```